# how to set resizing in td tag which is already working in th tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First of all, I am new to javascript.

I took a code for table resizing and its working fine for TH tag, but i want it on TD tag. I tried for a couple of hours and i can't figure it out

Here is the link

```
plnkr.co/edit/mYRdNuhuofYIERvA9wOI?p=preview
```

Here, `ob = getNodeName(ob, "TH");` i changed it into `TD` but its still not working.

So, i want the resize function in td tag instead of th tag.

Thanks for your help

Comment: hey, just download bootstrap library, this should very helpful for u, because that is fully responsive. http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @AshokSri yes. but i should not use any plugins. Thats y :(

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

give name to your td and write script

> `var tdname = document.getElementByTagName('tdname');`

Comment: i used only javascript